# Adding SOLR category refinement to cms page EE 1.9

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, solr

Add SOLR category refinement to cms page (which already include a widget that displays new products).

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?  I know you can't use php code within cms pages.  any directional attack vector suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: there are information missing. 1. Do you use the enterprise edition? 2. if not, what do you use to add SOLR? Do you already know how to add a widget to a cms page?

Comment: @Flyingmana I have enterprise edition, as it says in the header.  And yea, I know how to add a widget.. but some clarification would be nice.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35720/layered-navigation-on-cms-page You should be able to simply add the layered nav to the CMS page XML Layout, Solrs refinement or fauceted search overrides Magento's built-in one when Solr is enabled & Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation. `<reference name="left"><block type="enterprise_search/catalog_layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/></reference>`

Comment: @B00MER I dont really understand, care to expound upon your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMS > Pages > Manage content.

Page Information tabs > Design > Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="enterprise_search/catalog_layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Just ensure you are referencing the block of the Layout, this XML snippet would work for `2 columns with left bar` and `3 columns` layouts.

Hope that helps

Comment: Okay, I copied the above onto the CMS page's Layout Update XMLs section (with a 2 column with left bar configuation) and after saving it doesn't seem to show anything different in the CMS page preview.

Comment: CMS Preview may not show it properly, just content of the page, try saving and make sure to clear cache just in case. Tested this with 1.13.1.x EE.

Comment: The CMS preview takes you to the resolved url (if not, regardless, I manually entered the url).  Flushed the cache, still no sidebar. Did you just have a blank cms page with a sidebar? or anything else in the contents?

Comment: new install of 1.13.1.x, just took an existing out of box page, customer service, switched the layout to 2 column with left bar, pasted XML, saved and Shop By appears.

Comment: Strange, I give my css page a custom theme (change it to 'default') and the sidebar appaears.  In my theme, no dice.

Comment: is it possible to just add the sidebar as a widget of some sort?